# JavaFX can't load stylesheets: rootPane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString()); causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, css, url, javafx

I'm trying to load a CSS stylesheet with the following code in my controller's `initialize` method:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML BorderPane rootPane;
    @FXML TextField txtTest;
    @FXML Button btnSayHey;
    @FXML Button btnLookMa;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        String styleFile = "res/striped-progress.css";
        URL url = getClass().getResource(styleFile);
        rootPane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString());

    }
}
```

however upon launching the app, there's a `javafx.fxml.LoadException` being thrown and looking at the stacktrace, I can see that

```
rootPane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString());
```

is causing a `NullPointerException`. My start method is as follows:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    String sceneFile = "scripts/DEV/PLAYGROUND/STYLES/res/MainView.fxml";
    Parent root = null;
    URL    url  = null;

    try
    {
        url = new File(sceneFile).toURI().toURL();
        root = FXMLLoader.load( url );
        System.out.println( "  fxmlResource = " + sceneFile );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        System.out.println( "Exception on FXMLLoader.load()" );
        System.out.println( "  * url: " + url );
        System.out.println( "  * " + ex );
        System.out.println( "    ----------------------------------------\n" );
        throw ex;
    }

    BorderPane page = (BorderPane) root;
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("SampleCSS App - v1.0");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And console stacktrace is here:

```
    Exception on FXMLLoader.load()
  * url: file:/C:/rangedb/workspaces/UKRangeDBdemo/app_RVSW/scripts/DEV/PLAYGROUND/STYLES/res/MainView.fxml
  * javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/rangedb/workspaces/UKRangeDBdemo/app_RVSW/scripts/DEV/PLAYGROUND/STYLES/res/MainView.fxml

    ----------------------------------------

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/1545327692.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/rangedb/workspaces/UKRangeDBdemo/app_RVSW/scripts/DEV/PLAYGROUND/STYLES/res/MainView.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at DEV.PLAYGROUND.STYLES.ExternalStylesSample.start(ExternalStylesSample.java:79)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/897256917.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/661672156.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1517660793.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1349277854.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DEV.PLAYGROUND.STYLES.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:49)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application DEV.PLAYGROUND.STYLES.ExternalStylesSample
```

You'll notice that simply commenting out/deleting the line 
`rootPane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString());` in `initialize()` will cause all the errors to go away, but this will not load the CSS stylesheet.

**Update**:

Adding package structure under James_D's advice :
[image: package structure, my package is called 'STYLES']

Comment: "You'll notice that simply commenting out/deleting the line ..." - That surely means that you have already placed a breakpoint on line 49 of Controller.java and checked if it is `url` or some other part of the line that is `null`, right?

Comment: Why are you loading your resources from files? This will fail entirely when you bundle the application as a jar file, or if the application is run with a different working directory. You should be loading resources, not files.

Comment: @Axel debugger says that `rootPane` is `null` but shouldn't it be getting initialised as I'm using `FXMLLoader`?

Comment: @James_D This was a move more out of desperation. As I'm not packaging this as a `.jar` this isn't my priority now per se.

Comment: Well it might not be a priority now, but presumably at some point you *will* bundle it as a jar file. Do you really want to have to go back and rewrite all your resource-related code when you do? Use resources (i.e. `getClass().getResource()` to create the URLs and post your project structure if you can't get it working. Using files for things that are part of the actual application is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: However... that is probably an aside (though one you need to fix), since you now seem to be saying `rootPane` is null.

Comment: @James_D I see your point and after changing it, `getClass().getResource("res/MainView.fxml")` is returning `null` which is subsequently causing a NPE to be thrown on line 76 of `start()`. Readout on console is:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`

Comment: Then - obviously - the path to the FXML file is not correct. (No-one except you knows which line is line 76, by the way.)

Comment: How can I verify that it _really_ isn't correct? I've tried both "scripts/DEV/PLAYGROUND/STYLES/res/MainView.fxml" and "res/MainView.fxml" and both are causing a NPE.

Comment: Line 76 is basically: `root = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource("res/MainView.fxml") );`

Comment: You can verify that it really isn't correct by seeing if `getClass().getResource("res/MainView.fxml")` returns null. Don't you think you would be more likely to get help if you actually told people which package the class executing that code is in, and which package yor FXML file is in?

Comment: Package `DEV.PLAYGROUND.STYLES` where my logic is located. `DEV.PLAYGROUND.STYLES.res` is holding the fxml as you can see.

Comment: So then I would check that the FXML file and CSS file are being deployed to the build folder (i.e. the folder hierarchy where the class files are created, not where the source files are).

Comment: So it wasn't in the build folder but I took care of that problem now and I can use `getClass().getResource("res/MainView.fxml")` successfully. Still can't figure out why `rootpane` would be `null` in `rootpane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString());`

Comment: You haven't posted any code related to how `rootPane` is initialized, so there's no way to help with that.

Comment: I've updated the Q to include my whole `Controller` class. Basically I read somewhere that initialising a `@FXML` initialised field (e.g. `rootPane` in this case) would cause the object reference to be lost and performing operations on it wouldn't cause anything to change in the GUI. So my question is why rootPane is not being initialised by `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: And the FXML file?

Comment: Turns out I hadn't set the `fx:id` for the `BorderPane` object as `rootPane`. I also changed the line `rootPane.getStylesheets().add(url.toString());` to `rootPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("res/striped-progress.css").toExternalForm());` which works brilliantly. Thanks for nudging me along the way, I learnt a lot from this experience.

Answer (score 0):

(I've managed to fix my own problem thanks to James_D's comments. So here goes... )

The `NullPointerException` was being caused by me not initialising the BorderPane object in my `MainView.fxml` file. After setting the `fx:id` of the `BorderPane` in the fxml file as `rootPane` (note: this name was set to `rootPane` because in my `Controller`, I have a `@FXML` injected field:

```
@FXML Parent rootPane;
```

after making this change, almost all errors were gone. Except the following runtime warning:

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not find stylesheet: file:/C:/rangedb/workspaces/UKRangeDBdemo/app_RVSW/res/striped-progress.css
```

Albeit the CSS was being applied to my controls during runtime. Turns out one can load the stylesheet in a 'privileged' manner by simply using `toExternalForm()` on the `URL` object that was being returned by:

```
getClass().getResource("res/striped-progress.css")
```

In other words, I changed the above line of code to:

```
rootPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("res/striped-progress.css").toExternalForm());
```

`toExternalForm()` returns a `String` representation of the `URL` object but I'm not sure why not using it causes a warning and using it doesn't. Either way, it works.